# Time travel book series - Time agency alters humanity starting with the cro-magnons

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, genetic-engineering

I read a book a long time ago and can't remember the title. It has an agency that sends people back in time to make themselves powerful. The books all look forward to the time when the actual time arrives at the time when they began sending people back. The agency isn't portrayed as good, yet we follow several of the agents who are good people as they work from within to stop the agency. At one point they have genetically altered cro-magnons who are killers in the ancient past. There is something about Catalina Island that is important. I remember enjoying the books, but can't remember much else. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "a long time ago"? 10 years? 20 years? Do you recall any character names or descriptions? Any memories of the cover?

Comment: The question reminds me of the Orion series by Ben Bova, but I don't remember enough about it to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 16):

I found the series, it was "[The Company](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41665-the-company)" series by Kage Baker.

> In the 24th century, the Company preserves works of art and extinct
>   forms of life (for profit of course). It recruits orphans from the
>   past, renders them all but immortal, and trains them to serve the
>   Company, Dr. Zeus. One of these is Mendoza the botanist. She is sent
>   to Elizabethan England to collect samples from the garden of Sir
>   Walter Iden.  But while there, she meets Nicholas Harpole, with whom
>   she falls in love. And that love sounds great bells of change that
>   will echo down the centuries, and through the succeeding novels of The
>   Company.